# difference in two ways of declaring a class instance

Tags: c++, function, constructor, prototype

Assume we have a class with no default constructor:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(int data) : _data(data) { }
  int data(void) const { return _data; }
 private:
  int _data;
};
```

Why does this compile and what does it do:

```
Foo x();
```

Even though the above compiles, you can't do any of the following:

```
x.data();   // doesn't compile: request for member 'data' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'Foo()'
x->data();  // doesn't compile: request for member 'data' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'Foo()'
x().data(); // compiles!!! but linking fails with: undefined reference to `x()' 
x()->data();// doesn't compile:  base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Foo'
```

I guess I'm just confused about what adding the () after the x does, and why the language allows this?  Is this every allowable and/or useful?  It seems that no Foo instance is allocated on the stack either, because even with -Wunused-variable, no warning occurs about the x in `Foo x();`

In contrast, both of the following do not compile:

```
Foo *x = new Foo;  //  error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()
Foo *y = new Foo();//  error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()
```

This seems more consistent, I don't understand what is going on with `Foo x();`

EDIT: Ok, figured it out.  `Foo x()`; is a prototype for a function 'x', which takes no parameters and returns a Foo.  Since the function  isn't defined anywhere, trying to use it like a Foo instance (`x.data()`) or Foo pointer (`x->data()`) don't work.  `x()->data()` doesn't work because `x()` is of type `Foo`, not pointer to `Foo`.  `x().data()` compiles because `x()` returns `Foo`, which has a `data` method, but it fails to link because the function `x` has not been defined.  Whew.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Foo x();
```

This doesn't create object `x` of type Foo. Instead you are declaring a function `x` whose return type is `Foo`.

This [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2) entry should be helpful.

Now,

```
Foo *x = new Foo;  //  error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()
```

`new Foo` invokes the default constructor and you don't have one and is the reason for the error. If a class provides constructor then the default constructor is not provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo x();` is not a default constructed object of type Foo, but a function declaration: a function called x, taking no parameters and returning a Foo. Google for 'The most vexing parse'.

A default constructed object of type Foo would be simply `Foo x;`.